# Проблема с проверкой орфографии в Pycharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, проверка-орфографии

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой: когда я пишу код или комментарий на русском языке, то у меня все русские слова подчеркнуты зеленой волнистой линией (на скриншоте пару штук не подчеркнуты потому, что я их добавил в словарь

[image: Скриншот экрана]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 26):

Скорее всего у вас не установлена поддержка русского языка.

Зайдите в настройки (меню **File** -> **Settings**) и найдите раздел **Editor** -> **Natural Languages**

Справа будет список языков, а под ним иконка со знаком `+` для добавления дополнительных языков. Добавьте русский язык и всё должно заработать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнительную информацию ищите в доках плагина [Grazie](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/proofreading.html).

Answer (score -1):

Можно просто в settings.json добавить такую строчку: "cSpell.language": "en,ru",

согласно документации: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker-russian

Comment: Вопрос про PyCharm, а не про Visual Studio Code